# Best books on probability theory with examples for 11th,12th class and entrance exam

Tags: probability, reference-request, book-recommendation

What are the best books written on probability theory with examples for 11th,12th class(11th,12th class mean intermediate level or "A level"??And since to sit for the entrance exam it requires creative knowledge,so what are the recommended books for entrance exam ??Entrance exam refers to an admission test required to get admitted into a university on undergraduation level.

Comment: What does 11th, 12th class mean?

Comment: ....and Entrance Exam for what?

Comment: 11th,12th class mean "intermediate level" or "A level"...

Comment: Entrance exam to get admitted into a University on undergraduation level..